# Fill in missing group in multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, fillna

I have the following df:

```
date      family    ID    value
2019      abc       10    0.5
                    15    0.3 
          xyz       22    0.4
                    40    1.1
2020      xyz       22    1.9
                    46    0.3
```

I would like to forward fill `value` only if the `family` does not exist in a `date`. In the example above, the `ID` and `value` would forward fill to 2020 for abc, but not for xyz.

I have tried `df.unstack(['family','ID']).fillna(method = 'ffill')`, however this will incorrectly forward fill ID 40 for family xyz in the above example.

Desired result is :

```
    date      family    ID    value
    2019      abc       10    0.5
                        15    0.3 
              xyz       22    0.4
                        40    1.1
    2020      abc       10    0.5
                        15    0.3    
              xyz       22    1.9
                        46    0.3
```

Comment: `df.unstack(['family','ID']).ffill().stack(['family','ID'])` seems to work as expected.

Comment: Do you just have 2 years, or what should happen if abc also didn't exist in 2021? (would it get forward filled to all future years?)

Comment: abc would get forward filled until it appears again in a subsequent year, similar to fillna behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Once `unstack`, you probably need to check where there is no data for the family in a year, it can be done by `groupby.trasnform` with `any`. then use where on the `unstack` dataframe `ffill`ed to keep only the value you want to fill. use this in `fillna`. then stack back

```
df_u = df.unstack(['family','ID'])
df_ = df_u.fillna(
             df_u.ffill()
                 .where(~df_u.groupby(level='family', axis=1)
                             .transform('any'))
           ).stack(['family','ID'])
print (df_)
                value
date family ID       
2019 abc    10    0.5
            15    0.3
     xyz    22    0.4
            40    1.1
2020 abc    10    0.5
            15    0.3
     xyz    22    1.9
            46    0.3
```